# dplyr create column that calculate percentage based on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Year, Answer, Total
2017, Yes, 100
2017, No, 10
2017, Yes, 100
2018, No, 40
2018, Yes, 200
```

I'm trying to make a column that calculate the ratio between "No" to "Yes" in a given year. So it will look something like this:

```
Year, Answer, Total, Ratio
2017, Yes, 100, 1
2017, No, 10, 0.05
2017, Yes, 100, 1
2018, No, 40, 0.2 
2018, Yes, 200, 1
```

I'm using R and dplyr. I think I have to create a column with the total for "Yes" in a given year(there will be duplicates). Then make another column with an ifelse statement, where "Yes" rows will be 1 and "No" rows will be the total NOs divide by the Yes total. Is there a more efficient way to doing this? Thanks

Comment: how is NO 0.2 in 2018 ?

Comment: I don't think efficiency will matter for this. You can make it a one-liner, though it's much harder to read: `DF %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(v = (Total / sum(Total[Answer == "Yes"]))^(Answer == "No"))`

Comment: I would first `tidyr::spread` your answer column and then use `dplyr::mutate(ratio = value_no/value_yes)`  Oops, this won't directly work with ties. You'll need to sum up the values first as suggested by @Frank

Comment: @YOLO: No's as a share of Yes', or 40/200.

Comment: @Frank thanks that is what I was looking for, a one-liner instead of a two step process.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```r
library(dplyr)

xdf <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018),
  Answer = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
  Total = c(100, 10, 100, 40, 200)
)

xdf %>% 
  group_by(Year, Answer) %>% 
  summarise(Total = sum(Total)) %>% 
  mutate(share = if_else(Answer == "No", Total/lead(Total), 1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Year [2]
#>    Year Answer Total share
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2017 No        10  0.05
#> 2  2017 Yes      200  1   
#> 3  2018 No        40  0.2 
#> 4  2018 Yes      200  1
```

Comment: Hm, you have one fewer rows than the OP's expected output ..? Maybe need mutate instead of summarise.

Comment: True, I summed up the duplicates, which, arguably, makes the data tidier. If that is not wanted, one can `left_join` on `Year` and `Answer` (and `select(-Total` before)

Comment: this worked for me, but I will have to keep the original records. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a custom function

```
# function calculating the ratios
f1 <- function(k){
   ind.yes <- intersect(which(df$year == df$year[k]),
                        which(df$answer == "yes")
               )
   ind.no <- intersect(which(df$year == df$year[k]),
                       which(df$answer == "no")
             )
   total.yes <- sum(df$total[ind.yes])
   total.no <- sum(df$total[ind.no])

   ratio.no.yes <- total.no/total.yes
   return(ratio.no.yes)
}

# vapplying function f1
ratios <- vapply(1:nrow(df), f1, numeric(1))

# binding the data
df$ratios <- ratios
```

And here is the result (using a dummy data frame)

```
df <- data.frame(
                 year = sample(2015:2018, 10, replace = T),
                 answer = sample(c("yes", "no"), 10, replace = T),
                 total = sample(10:200, 10, replace = T),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
ratios <- vapply(1:nrow(df), f1, numeric(1))
df$ratios <- ratios

# printing
> df
  year answer total     ratios
1  2015    yes    76 0.08294931
2  2017    yes    43 2.55263158
3  2018    yes    63 0.00000000
4  2016    yes    61 0.83606557
5  2015     no    18 0.08294931
6  2017     no   142 2.55263158
7  2017    yes    33 2.55263158
8  2015    yes   141 0.08294931
9  2016     no    51 0.83606557
10 2017     no    52 2.55263158
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think efficiency will matter for this. You can make it a one-liner, though it's harder to read:

```
DF %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(v = 
  (Total / sum(Total[Answer == "Yes"]))^(Answer == "No")
)
```

This `x^cond` uses x^FALSE = x^0 = 1 to assign the desired value of 1 when Answer != "No".

Comment: Upgrading from a comment since the OP said this is what they were after.